# Using modules.exports in main Node file

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, export, require

I initialized my socket.io server in my server.js file (main entry point).

**EDIT 2:** Importing otherfile.js in this file also

```
// server.js
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const otherfile = require('otherfile.js');
io.use(//...configuration);
io.on("connection",otherfile);

module.exports = {io: io}
```

Now I want to use this same io object in another file

**EDIT 1:** To clarify, I am calling the exported variable in an export block like so:

```
// otherfile.js

const io = require('./server.js')['io'];

module.exports = {
    function(socket){
        // do stuff...
        io.emit("event", payload);
          }
}
```

When I run it, I get an error

```
Type Error: Cannot read '.on' property of undefined
```

Something like that.

Why can't I access code from the main js file?

Comment: The code looks okay. try `console.log`ging before the `module.exports` or just check log after `const io = require('./server.js') ` (not using the `io` subscript)

Comment: Can you try to directly export the `io` instance : `module.exports = io;` and import it again on the other file `const io = require('./server.js');`

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I tried logging the results, i.e console.log(io), still undefined

Comment: @Treast Yes, I tried that too.

Comment: Ohh, I just figure it out : try : `const io = require('./server')['io'];` with your initial export.

Comment: @Treast I am already doing that in "otherfile.js". Where are you talking about? Thanks.

Comment: Add `console.log(module.exports, io)` to end of `server.js` file. Then see the std output.

Comment: @LeanKhan remove the `.js` of the import string

Comment: @Treast I removed the '.js' from the require statement then console.logged the variable, still undefined :/

Comment: @hoangdv Hey, I hust did that `console.log(module.exports, io)` and the output is as expected, the exports object with the socket object. All fine, but  when in 'otherfile.js' it's still undefined. Strange though. My other imports and exports from other files are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after reading [this great article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8) (well, parts of it :p) about requiring modules in Node. Under "Circular Module Dependency".

The problem was, I was exporting the `io` object *after* I had required the 'otherfile.js' so the `io` object had not yet been exported and therefore undefined in 'otherfile.js' when the code is called.

So just export `io` object before requiring 'otherfile.js'.

```
// server.js
module.exports = {
     io: io
     }
 const otherfile = require("otherfile.js");
 // listen for events...
```